# How can I use html tag in this javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, oop

How can I use html tag in this javascript?

First of all, why `<br>` doesn't work in prompt.  Secondly, why can't I use tags for this code (poundOne.pound) to make the font larger by using css or html code such as `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<h3>`... or `<div style="......">`?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">


function poundToKgConvertor( pound ){
    this.pound = pound;
    this.convertorDon = convertor;
}
function convertor(){
    var convert = this.pound * 0.453592;
    return convert;
}

var poundOne = new poundToKgConvertor(prompt ("Convert Pound to Kilogram!<br> Please insert your    number of pound!"));
</script>

</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">


document.write(poundOne.pound +  " Pound = " + poundOne.convertorDon() + " <b>Kilogram</b>");

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `prompt` function only accept plain text.

Comment: Which JS isn't working — `var poundOne` or the `document.write`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use HTML in prompt/alert dialogs. However you can use new line characters:

```
prompt ("Convert Pound to Kilogram!\n Please insert your number of pound!");
```

Comment: Thank you!
but anyone knows about my second question?

Comment: Sorry, what is the seconds question? Why you can't use HTML there? The answer: because prompt/alert is not a part of HTML structure, it's not DOM.

Comment: yes i know is not part of HTML. Second question: why can't I use tags for this code (poundOne.pound) to make the font larger by using css or html code such as <h1>, <h2>, <h3>... or <div style="......">?

Comment: not sure I get it: http://plnkr.co/edit/usI0GEAs0uK4Hzz6oYhv?p=preview